# xrandr reports size "not found in available modes" when coming from wine

Tags: nvidia, wine, resolution, xrandr

My monitor's native resolution is 1680x1050.  I can switch to another resolution with

```
xrandr -s 1280x960
```

and then switch back with

```
xrandr -s 1680x1050
```

without a problem.

However, if I run XCOM: Enemy Unknown with wine, it switches the resolution to 1280x960, and then when I exit, it never resets the resolution back.  If I then try to use the same `xrandr -s 1680x1050` command, I get:

```
Size 1680x1050 not found in available modes
```

In order to get back my native resolution, I need to use `nvidia-settings`.  (After switching back, `xrandr` starts working again.)  Any idea how to get `xrandr` to work in this situation?

Or, even better, how can I get wine to stop dumping me in 1280x960 mode?

**Setup:**

- Xubuntu 12.10
- Xfce 4.10, compositing disabled
- Nvidia Geforce GT 240, driver 304.88
- wine 1.5.30

`xrandr` reports

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 270mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
   640x400        70.1  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

*Edit:* If I use `xrandr --verbose` after exiting the game, I note that I can change to any resolution / refresh rate that has `+HSync` but not any that has `-HSync` (which is what my 1680x1050 hash).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper solution, but a workaround is to change resolutions manually with `xrandr -s 1280x960` before starting the game.  This makes the `xrandr -s 1680x1050` command work after the game exits.